# apache RewriteRule as new name URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

Friends

http://testing.com/HotelName/Rooms is my original URL it shows all room details of that
hotel, but I want same details as HotelName.testing.com but I am not registered HotelName.testing.com in DNS

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/Rooms$  http://$2.example.com [R]
```

is showing error menas DNS not found

Any suggestions

Comment: You cannot use `HotelName.testing.com` until it is registered.

Comment: I need alias of "http://testing.com/HotelName/Rooms" to HotelName.testing.com in apache level, page serving from http://testing.com/HotelName/Rooms but url has to show HotelName.testing.com

Comment: Without a DNS entry, no amount of configuration from apache will make this work.

Comment: @anubhava we have the domain name ie.. testing.com in our example. what we want is a to create a url that looks like a new subdomain - hotelname.testing.com

Comment: You cannot use `hotelname.testing.com` without having a DNS entry.

Comment: @anubhava we registered as *.testing.com, it serves anything.testing.com, need alias url to this http://testing.com/HotelName/Rooms to HotelName.testing.com

Comment: Can you `ping` `HotelName.testing.com`

Comment: yes @anubhava, its pinging

Comment: ok when you open `hotelname.testing.com/HotelName/Rooms` in browser does it show same page as `testing.com/HotelName/Rooms`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)ablogapart.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://michaelkrol.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect the pages to new domain.

Comment: I need alias of "testing.com/HotelName/Rooms"; to HotelName.testing.com in apache level, page serving from testing.com/HotelName/Rooms but url has to show HotelName.testing.com